# TS Syntax for Destructured Function Params

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why do I have to specify two different literals basically just to specify a type for an incoming param for a JS function when dealing with TS?

Example:

```
export default function createGravatarImageUrl({ email }: { email: string }) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: So the compiler knows the type? I dont understand the question.

Comment: What exactly is your question? "*Why?*" seems opinion-based or require a language designer as an authoritative source. And you already seem to know the "*How?*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument binding and type here do two totally different things:

1. The argument binding `{ email }` destructures the object to bind the `email` var to the corresponding property in that arg.
2. The type can be any subtype of `{ email: string }` and bounds the type of that whole argument to something possibly more specific.

You're not specifying the parameter twice, you're specifying the destructuring action and the type of the whole argument separately. Unfortunately there's no shortcut if you want to do both and specify the type to exactly what you've destructured, but that's a pretty narrow case.

Comment: I think op understood that already? Not sure though.